# Commas in \clist_map_inline:nn split values in undesired places

Tags: syntax, comma-separated-list

I am curious about the workings of `\clist_map_inline:nn`. I have a list of sentences. This list is has no fixed length. Sometimes, the list may contain 2 sentences, or 10 sentences etc. So, I came across `\clist_map_inline:nn` which is exactly what I wanted, but then it splits on comma's. For example, if the list contains {a,b,c}, the end result is

> - a
> - b
> - c

However when you consider the example `{To respond quickly and efficiently to all in-coming sales enquiries, by telephone, fax and email,Create Develop and maintain strong working relationship with existing and potential Customers}`, I want the output to be

> - To respond quickly and efficiently to all in-coming sales enquiries, by telephone, fax and email
> - Create Develop and maintain strong working relationship with existing and potential Customers

Instead, the output I get is

> - To respond quickly and efficiently to all in-coming sales enquiries
> - by telephone
> - fax and email
> - Create Develop and maintain strong working relationship with existing and potential Customers

Apparently the command `\clist_map_inline:nn` splits the sentences at *every* comma. Is there any way to get the desired output?

Comment: You can "hide" the commas using `{`...`}`: `{{To respond quickly and efficiently to all in-coming sales enquiries, by telephone, fax and email},{Create Develop and maintain strong working relationship with existing and potential Customers}}`.

Comment: Thanks That works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any comma in the input defines an item: there's no way to distinguish a “grammatical comma” from a “separator comma” if they're at the same brace level.

Besides bracing each item, which might be awkward, you can use a different method, with another separator.

```latex
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_egregfors_chorelist_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\chorelist}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_egregfors_chorelist_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \begin{itemize}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_egregfors_chorelist_seq { \item ##1 }
  \end{itemize}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Now the input

```latex
\chorelist{
  To respond quickly and efficiently to all in-coming sales enquiries, by telephone, fax and email
  \\
  Create Develop and maintain strong working relationship with existing and potential Customers
}
```

will have the expected output.